# intensity slicing opencv (with the kinect)

Tags: java, image-processing, opencv, javacv

I would like to segment a part of an image (video stream), between 2 gray images.

When the stream starts, I take an image. Then I make another IplImage but where each pixel's intensity is added by a number. Now i would like to keep everything between these 2 image.

My code atm

```
 // Get the initial image 
 depthInit.copyFrom(result.getBufferedImage());  

 //Create an image where every intensity is 10, which will be added to the initial image.
 cvSet(scalarImage,cvScalar(10, 0, 0, 0));

 // De init image wordt verhoogt met de hoogte van de laag 
 cvAdd(depthInit, scalarImage, depthInitLayer2, null);
```

The 2 threshold images are : depthInit and depthInitLayer2

The stream is the variable "result"

Now to use these 2 image to threshold the stream

```
cvZero(difference);

// Select everything that is greater than the depthInit image
cvCmp(result, depthInit, difference, CV_CMP_GT);


cvZero(difference2);

// Select everything that is smaler than the depthInitLayer2 
cvCmp(difference, depthInitLayer2, difference2, CV_CMP_LT);
```

Though unfortunately this is not working.

My question why ?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method "inrange" by opencv does the trick . In my case (with some renamed variables)

```
 cvInRange(result, threshold1, threshold2,  difference2);
```

The results of 1 pixel in the stream (output) :

```
Stream value (189.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
threshold1 value (187.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
threshold2 value (217.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
After thresholding value (255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

This pixel with intensity 189 is in the interval of [217,187] so it's gets a 255 (white)

On the other hand this pixel with intensity 240 is not in the interval , so gets 0

```
Stream value (240.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
threshold1 value (187.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
threshold2 value (217.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
After thresholding value (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```